# Minimize a frame with a fixed size in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I am using wxPython and I want to fix the size of the Frame, so the user can not change it. 
This code is for a "normal" fcrame:

```
wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, pos=(150,150), size=(450,620))
```

With the code below the user can not change the size of the frame, but I am also losing the possibility of minimizing the window.

```
wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, pos=(150,150), size=(450,620), style= wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX)
```

Does anybody know how can I have a fixed size frame which I can also minimize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `wx.MINIMIZE_BOX`

```
import wx

app = wx.App()
window = wx.Frame(None, style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.CLOSE_BOX)
window.Show(True)

app.MainLoop()
```